# Unable to load PyDev Plugin in Jupyter Notebook

Tags: python, kernel, pydev

While running a program in Jupyter Notebooks, I receive the message that "The kernel appears to have died. It will restart automatically." I then receive the following error in my terminal:

WARNING:root:kernel f4121baf-31f9-45d7-a0f8-7b40b5ae4d18 restarted
Unable to load extension: pydevd_plugins.extensions.types.pydevd_plugin_pandas_types

I first uninstalled and reinstall a variety of python libraries as well as Jupyter Notebooks and Anaconda. I then tried updating my existing packages and downgrading my version of PyDev. However, the error persisted.